# Where is my project located on the SVN server?

Tags: linux, svn, repository, file-location, svn-server

I have a SVN server on a remote Pi, I have SSH access to it.

I use it mainly to store revisions of web projects that I do, so I wanted to set up a continuous integration environment, so that every day at 20 it compiles everything up and deploys it.

So I was searching for the SVN folder on my remote computer, I created the SVN server as

```
svnserve -d -r /home/pi/external_hdd/svn_root
```

Now, I created a "welcome" project, just to test if it was working. The project got successfully created, I have a `welcome` folder under `svn_root`. I committed a bunch of files into it, they got committed succesfully.

The problem is, if I list the contents of the `welcome` folder on the server, I see

```
drwxrwxrwx 6 pi pi 4096 Aug  9 21:50 .
drwxrwxrwx 3 pi pi 4096 Aug  9 21:50 ..
drwxrwxrwx 2 pi pi 4096 Aug  9 21:50 conf
drwxrwsrwx 6 pi pi 4096 Aug 10 09:31 db
-rwxrwxrwx 1 pi pi    2 Aug  9 21:50 format
drwxrwxrwx 2 pi pi 4096 Aug  9 21:50 hooks
drwxrwxrwx 2 pi pi 4096 Aug  9 21:50 locks
-rwxrwxrwx 1 pi pi  229 Aug  9 21:50 README.txt
```

I would like to have the files I committed, in order to compile them and copy them on the server.

Where is the code I committed?

Comment: *"I would like to have the files I committed, in order to compile them and copy them on the server."* -- why...? Rather than trying that, you should checkout the files on the server on which you want to compile them.

Comment: @Arjan Good question. I would like to do it because the machine which has the server is the same that holds the svn repository. So why duplicating things with a checkout on a machine that already has all files it needs to compile?

Comment: And then where would you expect the compiled code to end up? Surely you don't want compiled code in your repository? Yes, you should check out the (trunk of) the files you want to build, even if that's on the same machine.